# How does LIMIT in MySQL query make it possible to cancel stream

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I am wondering how does LIMIT in query prevent application thread reading from MySQL stream from hanging in close operation, and why does limit enable query canceling which is otherwise not working.

```
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

// Statement statement = connection.createStatement(); // this can be canceled

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        // tries to cancel query after streaming starts
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
                statement.cancel(); // does nothing when streaming
               // statement.close(); // makes application thread hang
            } catch (SQLException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    // adding limit to the query makes it possible to cancel stream, even if limit is not yet reached
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SOME_LONG_RUNNING_QUERY");

    int i = 0;
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println(++i);
    }

    connection.close();
```

Regular(non-streaming) query can be safely canceled, with or without limit. In streaming mode however, close/cancel operations simply make application thread hang/do nothing, presumably while performing blocking read on socket.

If i add some large LIMIT to the long running query then, as expected, `cancel()` operation results with:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLQueryInterruptedException: Query execution was interrupted
```

I understand there are a couple of questions on this matter but none of them discusses aspects bellow:

- Why does LIMIT make it possible to cancel streaming query
- Can this bug-feature be relied upon, can it be changed in next releases, is there any official explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

Limit make is so only a certain amount of records are pulled from the database. **Limit** is useful and is the best case to use in case you have a large query that is subject to hang.

In your case, when you are streaming your query that has both, a limit and close statement, it follows the order of operation. Since LIMIT comes first it will in result end your query. This would explain why even though you have a close statement it does not reach it and why you receive the exception.

I hope this clears up some of the issues you are having.